# Proof for convex preference relation

Tags: microeconomics, preferences

⪰ is a strictly convex preference relation on a set X which is the set of all N-tuples of nonnegative real numbers. Further are x,y,z element of this set X and i have the preferences x ≻ y ≻ z given.

How can i show that there exists a unique t ∈ R with y = tx + (1 − t)z?

My approach is the following. I have a convex linear combination for y which lies between x and z, which is also represented in the preferences. I guess this is true for every t ∈ (0,1). So in between this open interval there is a unique solution. But how can i show that in detail?

Comment: Strictly convex preferences only make sense on a convex set. This rules out the natural numbers. And the result will generally not hold on convex domains either. The lexicographic ordering on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is strictly convex but violates your condition.

Comment: So that ⪰ is a striclty convex preference relation on X = (R_+)^N does not make sense?

Comment: It does, but not on the set of natural numbers.

Comment: does (R_+)^N mean all positive real numbers or all natural numbers?

Comment: Neither. It is the set of all N-tuples of nonnegative real numbers.

Comment: okay thanks, so i summarized the task wrong. If i deal now with this kind of set, is there a possiblity to show that y = tx + (1-t) z for a unique t element of R?

Comment: No, I gave a counterexample in my first comment. You can show it under the assumption that preferences are continuous.

Comment: Actually, continuity is not enough either.

Comment: Couldn't you prove it as follows? Let t and t' so that y=tx+(1-t)z and also y=t'x+(1-t')z. It follows that (t-t')x=(t'-t)z which is possible only if t=t'. Hence, t is unique.